# Sending a string with 000 at beginning in C

Tags: c, sockets, iot

I posted this problem a couple of hours ago, but unfortunately, the details was not clear. i've added the code and some explanation.
i have a string like this to send through socket: "000f45546874684498765" as you see the first 3 numbers are zero, when the C compiler comes to this 000 it thinks these zeros are the finishing of the string. any suggestion?

```
proc_socketgps(s32 TaskId)
 while (1)
{
Ql_Sleep(socket_timer);
if (is_socket_success == TRUE)
{
    APP_DEBUG("start socket connect\r\n");
    APP_DEBUG("m_tcp_state :%d\r\n", m_tcp_state);
    APP_DEBUG("STATE_SOC_SEND :%d\r\n", STATE_SOC_SEND);
    APP_DEBUG("m_socketid :%d\r\n", m_socketid);

    proc_handle("\x00\x11\x22", sizeof("\x00\x11\x22"));
}



static void proc_handle(unsigned char *pData, s32 len)

char *p = NULL;
s32 iret;
u8 srvport[10];

//command: Set_APN_Param=<APN>,<username>,<password>
p = Ql_strstr(pData, "Set_APN_Param=");
if (p)
{
Ql_memset(m_apn, 0, 10);
if (Analyse_Command(pData, 1, '>', m_apn))
{
    APP_DEBUG("<--APN Parameter Error.-->\r\n");
    return;
}
Ql_memset(m_userid, 0, 10);
if (Analyse_Command(pData, 2, '>', m_userid))
{
    APP_DEBUG("<--APN Username Parameter Error.-->\r\n");
    return;
}
Ql_memset(m_passwd, 0, 10);
if (Analyse_Command(pData, 3, '>', m_passwd))
{
    APP_DEBUG("<--APN Password Parameter Error.-->\r\n");
    return;
}

APP_DEBUG("<--Set APN Parameter Successfully<%s>,<%s>,<%s>.-->\r\n", m_apn, m_userid, m_passwd);

return;
}

//command: Set_Srv_Param=<srv ip>,<srv port>
p = Ql_strstr(pData, "Set_Srv_Param=");
if (p)
{
Ql_memset(m_SrvADDR, 0, SRVADDR_BUFFER_LEN);
if (Analyse_Command(pData, 1, '>', m_SrvADDR))
{
    APP_DEBUG("<--Server Address Parameter Error.-->\r\n");
    return;
}
Ql_memset(srvport, 0, 10);
if (Analyse_Command(pData, 2, '>', srvport))
{
    APP_DEBUG("<--Server Port Parameter Error.-->\r\n");
    return;
}
m_SrvPort = Ql_atoi(srvport);
APP_DEBUG("<--Set TCP Server Parameter Successfully<%s>,<%d>.-->\r\n", m_SrvADDR, m_SrvPort);

m_tcp_state = STATE_NW_GET_SIMSTATE;
APP_DEBUG("<--Restart the TCP connection process.-->\r\n");

return;
}

//if not command,send it to server
m_pCurrentPos = m_send_buf;
Ql_strcpy(m_pCurrentPos + m_remain_len, pData);

m_remain_len = Ql_strlen(m_pCurrentPos);


if (!Ql_strlen(m_send_buf)) //no data need to send
        break;

    m_tcp_state = STATE_SOC_SENDING;
    do
    {
        ret = Ql_SOC_Send(m_socketid, m_pCurrentPos, m_remain_len);
        APP_DEBUG("Message Data :%s", m_pCurrentPos);
        APP_DEBUG("<--Send data,socketid=%d,number of bytes sent=%d-->\r\n", m_socketid, ret);
        if (ret == m_remain_len) //send compelete
        {
            m_remain_len = 0;
            m_pCurrentPos = NULL;
            m_nSentLen += ret;
            m_tcp_state = STATE_SOC_ACK;
            break;
        }
        else if ((ret <= 0) && (ret == SOC_WOULDBLOCK))
        {
            //waiting CallBack_socket_write, then send data;
            break;
        }
        else if (ret <= 0)
        {
            APP_DEBUG("<--Send data failure,ret=%d.-->\r\n", ret);
            APP_DEBUG("<-- Close socket.-->\r\n");
            Ql_SOC_Close(m_socketid); //error , Ql_SOC_Close
            m_socketid = -1;

            m_remain_len = 0;
            m_pCurrentPos = NULL;
            if (ret == SOC_BEARER_FAIL)
            {
                m_tcp_state = STATE_GPRS_DEACTIVATE;
            }
            else
            {
                m_tcp_state = STATE_GPRS_GET_DNSADDRESS;
            }
            break;
        }
        else if (ret < m_remain_len) //continue send, do not send all data
        {
            m_remain_len -= ret;
            m_pCurrentPos += ret;
            m_nSentLen += ret;
        }
    } while (1);
    break;
```

the code has been added to the question. firs socket gets open and gets connected to the server. this function >> proc_handle("\x00\x11\x22", sizeof("\x00\x11\x22")); sends hexadecimal string, however i think c consider this part "\x00" as end of the string ! and the data won't be sent ! I already tested that if I remove "\x00" from the row above it works like a charm !

Comment: Don't use string functions - which do use `\x0` as the terminator - when you actually have a byte buffer and length. Eg, you should be using `memcpy` instead of `strcpy`. Anyway, you should reduce this to a complete example (ie, including your `Q_*` functions) and a specific question with no TCP code if you want a detailed answer.

Comment: And please stop saying "the C compiler". Your problem is not a compilation problem. Saying "the C compiler" implies a compilation failure or other compiler problem when in fact the issue manifests at run time.

Comment: @Useless I think it would work!  thank you